# Will Wingdings or Webdings screw up my computer?

Tags: windows, fonts

We're learning Word in a computer class. My teacher said not to use any form of Wingdings or Webdings, claiming that it would mess up a computer system so he would reject such submissions.

Three questions here:

1. Will it actually mess up a computer system?
2. I thought that Wingdings is a critical Windows font. Wouldn't Windows not work if you deleted it?
3. Could you delete Wingdings or is it locked?

Comment: Heh. That's a good one. Gave me a nice giggle.

Comment: **Thank you all for your effort. This session has been sponsored by B.S. Buster!**

Comment: @B.S.Buster why not leave it?

Comment: Questions are meant to not solely help you, but to also be a benefit for anyone else on the internet that has an interest in the same problem; which is why you can't ask for it to be deleted once answered unless you do this by a legal requests like DCMA which do not apply in this case. The sole thing you can ask is to have your account disassociated with the question and your name removed from the comments here, but since this is already a fake name it probably won't make a difference either. Also, don't talk bad about people in public; even though you are anonymous it culd end up worse...

Answer (score 6):

1. No it won't mess up your system. These fonts are parts of the standard Windows installation. If there was a problem with them it would have been solved by now.
2. I don't think these fonts are critical to Windows - though I wouldn't be surprised to find that some characters were used in some system messages. If you deleted these fonts Windows would still work, but you might find that some messages don't display correctly.
3. You can delete most things in Windows - even system critical components - so I would expect you would be able to delete these fonts.

Having said that I would recommend that you don't use these fonts if your teacher has told you  not to. If only for his sanity.

Comment: Plus it's just tacky to use those in documents. It makes people assume you're a 12 year old.